# then prove that : $AB \mid \mid DC\mid \mid EF$

Tags: geometry

[image]

then prove that :
$$AB \mid \mid DC\mid \mid EF$$

Comment: This is joust Thales theorem.

Comment: It's not Thales. I think it's reversed to the Thales's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The hint.

Let $C_1\in BF$ such that $DC_1||EF.$

Thus, by Thales we have $$\frac{AD}{DE}=\frac{BC_1}{C_1F},$$
which gives $$\frac{BC}{CF}=\frac{BC_1}{C_1F}.$$
Can you end now?

Comment: It's the hint. Try to end it.

Comment: how $$\frac{AD}{DE}=\frac{BC_1}{C_1F},$$

Comment: Fricul38 By Thales. Because $DC_1||EF$.

Comment: What is this Thales theorem? To me, Thales theorem says that the hypotenuse of a right triangle is a diameter of the circumcircle. That hardly seems relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine to move parallelly the lines $AE$ and $BF$ towards each other until the points $A$ and $B$ coincide and it is formed the triangle $AEF$. Now note:
$$\frac{AD}{DE}+1=\frac{BC}{CF}+1 \Rightarrow \frac{AE}{DE}=\frac{BF}{CF},$$
which is the Thales intercept theorem. It follows $CD||EF.$

Answer (score 0):

**Given** $ \frac{AD}{DE} = \frac{BC}{CF} $

**To Prove** $ AB \mid \mid CD \mid \mid EF $

**Construction** Join $AF$.

[image]

**Proof**

*In* $∆AEF \ \text{&} ∆ABF$,

$ \frac{AD}{DE} = \frac{AG}{GF} = \frac{BE}{EF} $          ....($1$)

$ \implies DG \mid \mid EF $ and $  GC \mid \mid AB $ [By Converse of Thales' Basic Proportionality Theorem or [Intercept Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) ]

$ \implies  DC \mid \mid EF \mid \mid AB 
\ \square $